# not found RokSprocket Module in after installing in joomla

Tags: joomla, module

When I go to **extensions->manager** I found the `RokSprocket` module, but when trying to access **extensions->manager** I did not see the module and did not find this model.

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

you should after installing the module,go to **module manager>your module setting,**
you should there set position of module according your template.and  menu publish change to activated.

goodluck